# Jersey REST call working in browser not in client

Tags: java, jersey

I've been looking at the other examples for an hour and none of them seem to be the same.  I am doing a sample app and it works in the browser, however, with my client it is returning a 404 `NotFoundException` when trying to do the `GET`.  Here is the client code:

```java
public Activity get(String id) {
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/exercise-services/webapi/");

    Activity response = target.path("activites/" + id).request().get(Activity.class);

    return response;
}
```

And here is the `junit`:

```java
@Test
public void testGet() {
    ActivityClient client = new ActivityClient();

    Activity activity = client.get("1234");

    System.out.println(activity);
    assertNotNull(activity);

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is exactly the same code running at your client too?

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your REST service class?
Your code worked for my own services

Comment: This is not a very good answer. It would be much more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I miss-typed the object initialization as-

```
private ActivityRepository activityRespository = new ActivityRepositoryStub();
```

instead of

```
private ActivityRepository activityRepository = new ActivityRepositoryStub();
```

Thanks for the responses.  It seems to work now.